# Practical way to set up an email inbox for testing?

Tags: email

I need to test a high-volume email application.  Up to now, I've just been using gmail ad-hoc aliases (myaccount+whatever@gmail.com) to receive emails and see that the content is right.  However, I now need to verify a recipient list, which means I need to get every single email that goes out on a particular test run.  The problem with Google isn't clear, but there's some throttling somewhere (perhaps from SendGrid, who is my delivery provider), and only a very small number of those emails ever make it to my acount.

So: what's a practical way to get where I want to be?  Is there a way to get gmail to just accept everything?  Is there a web app / service somewhere that will let me throw up a fake email address that can receive for a large number of recipients?  Is there something else?

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking this. I really hate having to state the obvious but you could just set up a mail server using whatever OS and software takes your fancy and create as many mailboxes as you require.

Comment: Well..some of this "overthinking" is trying at all costs to avoid the IT department.  They aren't helpful.

Comment: Well, not at _all_ costs.